# Monitor File Changes On Windows System

Tags: monitoring, files

I am looking for a utility that can take a snapshot of the files in directories that I am interested in and then compare that snapshot to the current state of the system and show me any files that have been added, changed, or deleted. Does anyone know of solutions that provide this functionality?

Thanks,
Nate

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for a file integrity monitor (FIM), and I would suggest OSSEC. It runs natively on Windows and allows centralized configuration (if you need that).

Link: http://www.ossec.net

Comment: OSSEC is awesome for this. It might take a little bit of munging to get the exact data you want, but you can definitely export the last X days' worth of changes to a CSV and then parse it however you like (PowerShell works surprisingly well for this).

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk), a commercial, file integrity monitoring system for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I use Beyond Compare 2.

1. Right click on a directory, choose "Select Left Side to Compare".
2. Right click on another directory, choose "Compare to".
3. It lists all of the files in two vertical panes, showing the ones that are missing/changed/etc.
4. You can then drill down into each pair of files to see the changes at a file level.

It has quite a nice feature: if any files are different between a pair of directories, it changes the color of the icons. This allows you to instantly find any files that are different in the directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

It's not precisely what it's intended for, but Synctoy from Microsoft can be made to do what you're after.

Bob

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related question that might already have something for you.

[Utility to notify when website files are changed](https://serverfault.com/questions/24263/utility-to-notify-when-website-files-are-changed)

Answer (score 0):

Three options come to mind:

- Trip Wire http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/
- Sysinternals FileMon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896642.aspx
- A recursive directory MD5 hash check with Swiss File Knife http://sourceforge.net/projects/swissfileknife

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend UltraCompare or SyncBackSE.

UltraCompare allows you to compare directories full of files, then drill down to compare individual files.

SyncBackSE if quite easy to use. It compares two directories, gives a list of files that have changed, and offers the option to synchronize the directories. Its pre-configured out of the box, but if you want to do anything unique it has a whole bunch of configurable options. I use SyncBackSE to backup my files to Amazon S3 (and Gladinet to mount Amazon S3 to a drive letter).

Answer (score 0):

Another tool that also find changes in registry is Systracer

Link: http://www.blueproject.ro/systracer/